# Contour plot lines striking through inline labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making a contour plot with three arrays: `xdata`, `ydata`, and `phi`. I'd like the face-on axes to correspond to `xdata` and `ydata`, and make contours out of `phi`.

After looking through the [matplotlib contour plot example page](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html), I wrote:

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xdata, ydata)
Z1, Z2 = np.meshgrid(phi, phi)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.scatter(xdata, ydata, s=200, c='white', edgecolor='grey', zorder=2)
plt.xlabel("x (degrees)")
plt.ylabel("y (degrees)")
plt.title("Obscuration ellipse $\phi$ (radians)")
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z1, zorder=1)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=True, inline_spacing=3, rightside_up=True, fontsize=18)
plt.show()
```

Here, I'm using `zorder` to force the scatter points to show up on top of the contour.

On the plot I get, the contours strike through the inline labels:
[image: contour plot with strikethrough inline labels]

Some of these inline labels also appear to be stacked on top of others, and in two cases the labels obscure scatter points, despite `zorder` assignment.
How do I fix my code such that the labels are *not* strikethrough (as is the case in matplotlib's example page) and `zorder` is preserved?

Comment: Giving the face that you've done `inline=True`, my guess is that this problem is specific to your data. Do you minding sharing your `xdata`, `ydata` and `phi` with us?